# Botched Thingsboard upgrade from 2.5.6 to 3.0.0

Tags: thingsboard

In attempting to upgrade my Thingsboard CE instance I somehow broke something, and I don't know what.  I installed PostGres SQL 12.0 and when I run the upgrade script something is getting hung up.

Any hints as to what went wrong?

```
sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/upgrade.sh --fromVersion=2.5.0-cassandra
[sudo] password for xxxx
 ===================================================
 :: ThingsBoard ::       (v3.0.0)
 ===================================================

Starting ThingsBoard Upgrade from version 2.5.0-cassandra ...
Migrating ThingsBoard entities data from cassandra to SQL database ...
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:82)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
ThingsBoard upgrade failed!
```